# Future calls for DML Statements

Tags: apex

I am curious if there are any benefits of inputting my DML statements into future calls. When I bulk process 200 records at a time I often see the following statement:

> UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW

I have looked into the debug logs and it looks like most of the processing is coming from Workflows and process builder. Anyways, should I also reduce processing to 100 records at a time? Can I avoid this by using future calls?

Basically, to me this error is saying "Hey, I am currently being processed on, can you try again later"

Well if that's the case, would a future call help alleviate this?

Comment: Is this issue happening in the context of a batch job? a Bulk API data upload? something else?

Comment: Typically means that some other process is already modifying a record that your dml statement is trying to modify.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, this is happening in batch jobs and workbench.

Comment: shoutout to Advanced Apex 4th edition by Dan Appleman for patterns on resolving concurrency issues

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to resolve this issue by adding FOR UPDATE to the end of my query.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm